# Progress OpenEdge database with Phalcon

Tags: database, phalcon, openedge, progress-db, phalcon-orm

In one of my applications, I need to connect to a Progress OpenEdge database from Phalcon framework. I was looking for ODBC connection or ORM wrapper to the database.

Is there any plug-in/adapter available for this task?

Answer (score 1):

OpenEdge supports ODBC.  The Datadirect drivers are free.

Comment: [This page should help you find what you are looking for](https://www.progress.com/odbc/openedge)

Answer (score 0):

I have not found one so I made my own model class and query the databsase with odbc_connect(). But you could use it in-line if you don't want to go to the trouble.

To connect:

```
putenv("ODBCINI=/path_to/odbc.ini");
$this->conn = odbc_connect("DataBaseName","User","Password");
$this->table = "TABLE_NAME";
```

And query:

```
$rows = odbc_exec($self->conn,$sql);
while ($row = odbc_fetch_object($rows)){
    // do some stuff
}
```

Read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.uodbc.php